# Can't get rails server to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to start my rails server in the environment "mainstreet" this function in my config/site_config.rb file

```
def self.settings(env)
    answer = YAML::load_file('config/siteconfig.yml')[env]
    raise "No settings for environment #{env}" if answer.nil?
    answer
end
```

returns "No settings for the environment mainstreet" In siteconfig.yml I have:

```
mainstreet:
environment: mainstreet
S3_DOC_BUCKET: 
PPTX_GEN_SERVICE:
PDF_GEN_SERVICE: 
OBJ_THUMB_SERVICE: 
WINDOWS_CLIENT_URL: 
KM_KEY:
HOST_NAME: http://localhost:3000
```

and I have a mainstreet.rb file in /config with settings defined. I'm new to ruby, so I'm not sure whats going on here, I've never had an issue like this. Also, I'm using windows.

Here's the full trace:

Comment: How do you start the server?

Comment: First I set RAILS_ENV=mainstreet then do rails s -e mainstreet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the current directory isn't what you think it is...You need to specify the full path to your config file:

```
def self.settings(env)
    path = File.join(Rails.root, "config", "siteconfig.yml")
    answer = YAML::load_file(path)[env]
    raise "No settings for environment #{env}" if answer.nil?
    answer
end
```

EDIT:
Your config file is badly formatted, if what you have here is correct. It should be indented:

```
mainstreet:
    environment: mainstreet
    S3_DOC_BUCKET: 
    PPTX_GEN_SERVICE:
    PDF_GEN_SERVICE: 
    OBJ_THUMB_SERVICE: 
    WINDOWS_CLIENT_URL: 
    KM_KEY:
    HOST_NAME: http://localhost:3000
```

In a rails3 console, the file parses correctly:

```
irb(main):039:0> y = YAML.load_file("c.yml")["mainstreet"]
=> {"environment"=>"mainstreet", "S3_DOC_BUCKET"=>nil, "PPTX_GEN_SERVICE"=>nil, "PDF_GEN_SERVICE"=>nil, "OBJ_THUMB_SERVICE"=>nil, "WINDOWS_CLIENT_URL"=>nil, "KM_KEY"=>nil, "HOST_NAME"=>"http://localhost:3000"}
```

This assumes you're passing "mainstreet" as the value of `env` in your function

Comment: Still getting the same result, unfortunately. Two other people on my team, one using OSX and one using Linux are not experiencing this problem though. It also might be worth adding that I set rubyracer to not installer on windows, do you think not having that gem would make a difference?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I had tried that earlier, but must have been missing something else at the time, bc it did not work then.